# Firebase analytics : Collect analytics data for different ios application in one firebase project - flutter

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, google-analytics

I have 2 different iOS application in one firebase project. Need to collect the analytics in the same firebase project for both the iOS application. My problem is the analytics of both the app is mixing. How to collect them separatly in single firebase project.

Answer (score 0):

Projcet settings > general > my app

[image]

[image]

Comment: i have already creadted the apps but i need to record the analytics separately. Is there any way for it?